# How to dynamically change the slot values based on user view port?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a feedback popover towards right side of the page which is fixed. User can open the popover by clicking on helpful text and provide feedback on different sections.

Use case is something like this

1) If user is on top of the page and if he decides to provide feedback, then he would open popover and slot values would be one,two,three.

2) if user decides to scroll main page further down and now the top visible section in main page is five,six and seven... if he decides to provide feedback, then he would open popover and slot values would be five,six,seven.

![slot values five,six,seven]   https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Jop.jpg

How to automatically update slot values based on user view port.

Using `ng-repeat` to change slot values when clicked up and down

Here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rr0tislMoLiKNNP3FYZF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but should give you an idea how to improve it. Right now I am assuming you have similar height for all items, you can either constraint it or calculate them on the fly in the formula.

http://jsbin.com/xozoni/edit?html,js,output